# Advanced string manipulation in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and trying to do some advanced string splitting/replacement.

I have researched all over and read the common SO solutions but no luck.

I am trying to convert this string:

```
var feeling = "my code makes me {{ unhappy }}"

// your magic code here


console.log(feeling) >> "my code makes me happy!" // desired outcome
```

So i am trying to replace the brackets and words in them, with a new word..

I tried

```
feeling.replace(/{{.*}}/, 'happy !')
```

but it's not working.

Thank you!

Comment: are u sure it not working ?? its works

Comment: The code needs to **use the output** of the `replace` function as it *does not modify the string*: `console.log(feeling.replace(/{{.*}}/, 'happy !'))` will show the desired output.

Comment: try console.log(feeling.replace(/{{.*}}/, 'happy !')) . @user2864740 says.

Comment: I keep falling into this pit as well.

Answer (score 1):

As per the doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace here, The `replace()` method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. you just need to receive the output in `feeling` variable,

```js
var feeling = "my code makes me {{ unhappy }}";
    feeling = feeling.replace(/{{.*}}/, 'happy !');
    console.log(feeling);
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. What are you doing differently?

```js
var feeling = "my code makes me {{ unhappy }}";
// Guessing you failed to update "feeling" with the 
// return from .replace() here
feeling = feeling.replace(/{{.*}}/,'happy !');
console.log(feeling)
```